# Is there a workaround to assign VIEW SERVER STATE permissions to an Application Role in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

`GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE to [ApplicationRole]` fails an an application role is not  areal datbase principal.

Is there a workaround for granting `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions to an Application Role?

We want to read the latest results from the view `sys.dm_tran_commit_table`. Our application connects to the database using an Application Role and read change tracking data. Its needs to join the `CT TABLE` with this view to determine time at which the `ct version` was created.

Is there any other method using which the time for a `ct version` can be determined?

We are using SQL Server 2014 - 2018 and above with the latest service packs.

Thanks

`select * from sys.dm_tran_commit_table` does not return the latest data from the commit table for an ApplicationRole user.

Comment: *"We are using SQL Server 2014 - 2018"* There isn't a SQL Server 2018.

Comment: You could encapsulate the queries in a stored procedure and sign it with a certificate based on a user with `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission. The app role only needs execute permission on the proc.

Comment: @DanGuzman - I had the same thought, but suspect that there would need to be a shared cert between the user database and `master`, a login created based on the cert, and permissions granted to the login. I'll write it up later if it hasn't already been done.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to create a procedure that executes with owner that has access to sys.dm_tran_commit_table and just set permission to execute this procedure to the "luser"

Comment: @siggemannen it is not working, I still cannot see the latest commits.

Comment: @DanGuzman this is something which works, but we are looking for an easier alternative.

Comment: @DanGuzman, siggemanen would this work for a VIEW? Creating a view would allow us to join our existing queries with this view.

Comment: Did you actually add so proc is executed as owner

Comment: @user20130987, although only modules can be signed (not views), you can use a signed multi-statement table-valued function instead. Add the full query to your question and I'll post an answer with an example.